# MySQL update row with random number + string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to update a cell like this "12,3,54,66,43" (five numbers with comma in a single row)- Numbers need to be random and range between 1-100

here is SQL which I tried

```
UPDATE `mobilelk_funzone`.`feature_wallpaper` SET `wallpaper` = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 100) + "," +FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 100) + ","+FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 100) + ","+FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 100) + ","+FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 100) + "," WHERE `feature_wallpaper`.`id` = 1;
```

But this return only sum of the number not with ","

Comment: Your markup is wrong for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCAT` is your friend here:

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(RAND() * 100) + 1, '"', FLOOR(RAND() * 100) + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to update a cell like this "12,3,54,66,43" - Numbers need to be random and range between 1-100

i suggest following code do that:

random_number = mt_rand(1, 1000);